# Are all monomorphisms in the category of bounded lattices regular?

Tags: ct.category-theory, lattice-theory

Let $\mathbf{Lat}_{01}$ be the category of bounded lattices with lattice homomorphisms that respect the smallest and the largest element. Is there a monomorphism in $\mathbf{Lat}_{01}$ that is not regular?